# GDI+ - converting bitmap pixels to JPG format

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+

I have an array of a bitmap pixels. How can I convert them to JPG format and copy to another array? How to convert them back to bitmap from JPG pixels?

Comment: JPG is a **file** format.  There is no such thing as a "JPG pixel".  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the Encoder CLSID function from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533843(v=vs.85).aspx

Modified original code from https://vctipsplusplus.wordpress.com/tag/image-conversion-gdi/:

```
int main()
{
   // Initialize GDI+.
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
   CLSID   encoderClsid;
   Status  stat;
   Image*   image = new Image(L”Bird.bmp”);
   // Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
   GetEncoderClsid(L”image/jpeg”, &encoderClsid);
   stat = image->Save(L”Bird.png”, &encoderClsid, NULL);
   if(stat == Ok)
      printf(“Bird.png was saved successfully\n”);
   else
      printf(“Failure: stat = %d\n”, stat);
   delete image;
   GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
   return 0;
}
```

Just change image/jpeg to whatever format you want to convert. The details are given on the MSDN link I mentioned above. Of course to work with the pixels, you'll need to convert the JPEG to BMP

Answer (score 2):

You can create a memory stream using [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SHCreateMemStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then use the GDI+ method [`Image.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535406(v=vs.85).aspx) to save to the stream. Reverse the process to read back in.